# Can't seem to access certain posts on a public Facebook page

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I've been messing around with the Facebook graph API and I'm trying to pull the most recent 100 posts on a public Facebook page (https://www.facebook.com/MACcosmetics/?hc_ref=PAGES_TIMELINE&fref=nf).
However, when I do this for some reason certain posts aren't being pulled through the API - for example, the post on November 5th is not shown in the json object, however, the post below it on November the 4th is. I can't see any difference between the post so I don't understand why this would be the case?

Is anyone able to shed some light on this for me...

I've also included the code I used to pull this data below.

Thanks in advance,

Harry

```
response = requests.get('https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/16126780553/posts/?fields=message,shares,created_time&limit=100&include_hidden=True&access_token=XXXXX')
```

Comment: What type of access token are you using here?

Comment: Thanks for responding CBroe - this is driving me mad! I'm using an App ID with app secret.

Comment: Then it might simply be the case that some of those posts are targeted to specific audiences - those can’t be read using the app access token, but only with a user access token for a user that can see those posts, or a page access token.

Comment: I see - if they were targeted to specific audiences then I wouldn't have expected to see them visibly on their public page? How might I go about finding out if that definitely is the problem? 
I'm assuming a page access token requires me asking the brand for access to their page information?

Comment: I tried a regular user access token and it works! Any advice on how to debug this sort of thing in future? and THANKS!

Comment: _“then I wouldn't have expected to see them visibly on their public page?”_ – you are likely logged in when visiting that page - so whether the targeting criteria match, is determined against _your_ user account. Same thing happens when you use your user access token. And yes, a page access token requires admin access to the page.